# Filtering results of included rails model in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to filter out some results I get from an included model.

I have 3 classes:

```
Platform (has many Products, has many ProductImages through Product)
Product (has many ProductImages)
ProductImage
```

Now, I'm trying to get all the products and their associated images in a single query using ActiveRecord, that their images have a boolean field set to false:

```
platform.products.includes(:product_images).where(product_images: {dont_use: false})
```

The problem with the above query is that it filters out the products that don't have any product_images with dont_use:true which is not my goal.

I'm trying to get all the products with their associated images but just filter out images with dont_use: false.

Any idea on how to change my query to fit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding any conditions will modify the overall query defining which products are returned rather than specifying which images are included.

You could add an additional association with the condition that you need and include that. Eg:

```
class Product < Active record::Base
   has_many :images_in_use, -> { where(dont_use: false) }, class_name: ProductImage
end

platform.products.includes(:images_in_use)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will still invoke a query when running `platform.products.includes(:images_in_use).first.product_images` while I'm trying to eliminate the additional query by lazy loading the product images.

Comment: I would have expected you would call `first.images_in_use`. Either call `images_in_use` (because you only want certain images) or use `product_images` because you do actually want all images at some point. To me it seems like an either/or thing.

Comment: I used first.images_in_use

Comment: Awesome  glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

I think you have wrong `where` clause.

```
platform.products
        .includes(:product_images)
        .where('product_images.id is NULL OR product_images.dont_use = ?', true)
```

Comment: It effectively still yields the same results. It filters out the products that dont have any valid product images. I just want it to filter out the bad images, not the products...

Comment: Also, the query above was missing references: `products = platform.products.includes(:product_images).where('product_images.id is NULL OR product_images.dont_use = ?', false).references(:product_images)`

Comment: why don't you use `ProductImage.where(...)`?

Comment: essentially I want to get the products and their images (if they have any). If I go from the product images, I may miss out on products that dont have images.

Comment: I think you should use `group`